# Laravel 9 how to redirect to a custom route after registration in laravel jetstream

Tags: laravel, authentication, redirect, routes, laravel-jetstream

I'm using Laravel Jetstream and Laravel 9 for user login and registration. I have also implemented email verification after registration and it works fine.
The problem comes when I want to display a new page called "news" instead of "dashboard" after login and registration. After user login the "news" page is displayed correctly, but after registration of a new users it sends me directly to the news page and not to the email verification page.
How can I show the email verification page when a new user registers and only after he verifies his email, the "news" page appears?

I made this changes to show the news page :
In app/Providers/RouteServiceProviver file changed this line:

```
public const HOME = '/dashboard';
```

To this:

```
public const HOME = '/news';
```

In the web.php file I added this line to show the route

```
Route::get('news', [CustomViewController::class, 'showNews'])->middleware('auth')->name('news');
```

And the showNews function in the controller is:

```
public function showNews(){

        $user = auth()->user()->name;
        return view('newviews.news' ,compact('user'));
    }
```

And the view is this:

```
<x-app-layout>
    Welcome {{$user}}
</x-app-layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the config file of fortify.php what is the value of the equal home,
When the user is authenticated, it will be redirected to that value.

Comment: In config>fortify.php the value of Home is this: 'home' => RouteServiceProvider::HOME, so I think it takes the value of this Home of RouteServiceProvider: public const HOME = '/news'; but still redirecting to news page, instead of email verification page when a new user register

Comment: Maybe the configs are cached. Have you cleared the settings cache?